# ActionLink works locally but doesn't work with Host server. (Host4Life)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

So I have this in my Site.Master

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("ABOUT ME", "About", "Home")%></li>
```

Going to [AlainaChorney.com](http://alainachorney.com/) (My girlfriends soon to be site) loads up but then clicking the ABOUT ME link dies, and says the file/page isn't there.  I've checked the file structure and it is there on the host.

When I hover over the link it points to http://alainachorney.com/Home/About  as it should. 
When debugging locally I get this link => http://localhost:49165/Home/About which loads fine.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something....

I'm using Host4Life as a housing provider.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS 6?  Is this a shared host or a virtual server (i.e., does the host company control IIS or do you control IIS)?

IIS has to be configured to send ALL requests for your website through asp.net in order for routes to work correctly.  This is usually accomplished by configuring a [wildcard mapping in iis](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true) (making sure IIS does NOT check for the existence of the file).

If you can configure IIS on the server, you can do this yourself [(see here for more info)](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx).  If you can't, you have to have your host do this for you.  They might tell you to take it walking, however.  In that case, you'll have to find a MVC friendly host.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I ended up chatting with WebHost4Life.  They tried a few things on their end.  And while they were working on it I lost internet connection.  It didn't work the rest of the day, but then it started to work the next day.

I'll check it right since you pointed me toward the host :)